# Resizer to expand and minimize div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make 3 div side by side where each can expand to full screen when click a button while collapsing the other (but still show the title with vertical orientation). Something like [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pen/) did. Here is what it looks like in their page.
[image: 3 Equal Div side by side]
Initially it shows 3 equal size div side by side. And when you double click the resizer on the side it will expand one div and collapse the other but the collapsed div not hidden entirely.
[image: One div full screen and the other is collapsed]
I tried to inspect their page source and found this lines one code.

```
<div class="editor-resizer html-editor-resizer" title="Double-click to expand."></div>
<div id="box-html" class="box box-html" data-type="html">
   <div class="powers">
      <div class="powers-drag-handle" title="Double-click to expand."></div>
      <div class="editor-actions-left">
         <button id="settings-pane-html" class="button button-medium mini-button settings-nub" data-type="html" title="Open HTML Settings">
            <svg class="icon-gear" width="10" height="10">
               <use xlink:href="#gear"></use>
            </svg>
         </button>
         <h2 class="box-title html-editor-title" id="html-editor-title"><span class="box-title-name">HTML</span></h2>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="code-wrap">
      <pre id="html" class="code-box" aria-labeledby="html-editor-title">
         <code>

         </code>
      </pre>
      <div class="error-bar" id="error-bar-html">
         <span class="error-icon" data-type="html">
         !
         </span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But I can't find any javascript or css for this behaviour. How can I achieve this? Is there any plugin from jQuery or Bootstrap for this kind of component? Or do I have to create from scratch?

Comment: How didn't you find codes like `class="editor-resizer js-editor-resizer"` in the source code? There are too many of such codes in their source code. There are `css` and `js` corresponding to those classes. And I guess they have developed them by their own,

Comment: @RakibulIslam, yes you are right. Actually I can duplicate that page on my local page by copy all their required js library, but they seems to use hidden input to include some js which I don't understand how to copy. So now I tried to create the js for my own page.

Comment: For class like `editor-resizer`. I also tried to searching around hoping there are library for that but it seems it was their own class. Thats why I asking here because I don't know where to start create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start by doing your own minimal example like the below one that you can improve. I think its better than trying to reproduce a complex code like the codepen one:

*It works on the hover but you can easily make it on click with some JS*

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}

.container>div {
  flex: 1;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(red, red) left/15px 100% no-repeat, 
    blue;
  padding-left: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

.container:hover>div {
  min-width: 15px;
  padding: 0;
  flex: 0;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

.container>div:hover {
  flex: 1;
  padding-left: 15px;
  writing-mode: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>HTML</div>
  <div>CSS</div>
  <div>JS</div>
</div>
```

Comment: WOW...you are really amazing...+1 for your effort...The answer could not be anything simpler

Answer (score 0):

I've created a Vue component library. It has a understandable structure and has many helper events and props. Also it is touch friendly and supports vertical/horizontal split. [Github link](https://github.com/dgknca/vue-multi-split-pane)

```js
Vue.component('MultiSplitPane', VueMultiSplitPane.MultiSplitPane)
Vue.component('Pane', VueMultiSplitPane.Pane)

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Code&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Fira Code', monospace;
  background: #d8d1d9;
}

.v-pane-custom .v-pane .content {
  background: #fff;
}

.v-pane-custom .content .innerContent {
  padding: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.paneNested>.content>.innerContent {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <multi-split-pane split="horizontal" height="400px" width="1000px" resizerWidth="30px" classes="v-pane-custom">
    <Pane>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </template>
    </Pane>
    <Pane>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </template>
    </Pane>
    <Pane>
      <template v-slot:content>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
      </template>
    </Pane>
  </multi-split-pane>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.12/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-multi-split-pane@1.1.1/dist/vue-multi-split-pane.min.js"></script>
```